# Create vanishing button to transition between images

Tags: dynamic, button, eventhandler

I have multiple "slides" that I would like to transition between, by clicking a specific area on each slide. eg:

```
im1 = Module[{li}, 
 li = Thread[{{, , },
     CirclePoints[3]/2}]; 
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[None], FaceForm[GrayLevel[0.9]], Disk[{0, 0}], 
   Text[Button[Style[Magnify[#, 5]], 
       Appearance -> "None"], #2] & @@ First@li, 
   Text[Style[Magnify[#, 5]], #2] & @@@ Rest@li}, ImageSize -> 200]]

im2 = Module[{li}, 
 li = Thread[{{, , },
     RotateLeft[CirclePoints[3]/2, 2]}]; 
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[None], FaceForm[GrayLevel[0.9]], Disk[{0, 0}], 
   Text[Button[Style[Magnify[#, 5]], 
       Appearance -> "None"], #2] & @@ First@li, 
   Text[Style[Magnify[#, 5]], #2] & @@@ Rest@li}, ImageSize -> 200]]
```

I can transition between `im1` and `im2` with something like

```
DynamicModule[{i = 0}, 
 Style[EventHandler[Dynamic[{im1, im2}[[1 + Mod[i, 2]]]], 
   "MouseDown" :> ++i], {0, 2}]]
```

but the mouseclick isn't limited to a specific area (namely the  symbol).

How can I do this in mathematica?

Answer (score 2):

You may test where the mouse is when you click and depending on the position make the change or not. E.g.:

```
DynamicModule[{i = 0}, 
 Style[EventHandler[Dynamic[{im1, im2}[[1 + Mod[i, 2]]]], 
   "MouseDown" :> 
    If[0.13 < MousePosition["CellScaled"][[1]] < 0.2 && 
      0.2 < MousePosition["CellScaled"][[2]] < 0.5, ++i]], {0, 2}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do the trick:

```
li = {Thread[{{, , }, CirclePoints[3]/2}], 
  Thread[{{, , }, RotateLeft[CirclePoints[3]/2, 2]}]};

DynamicModule[{i = 0}, 
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[None], FaceForm[GrayLevel[0.9]], Disk[{0, 0}], 
   Dynamic[EventHandler[
     Text[Style[Magnify[li[[1 + Mod[i, 2], 1, 1]], 5]], 
      li[[1 + Mod[i, 2], 1, 2]]], "MouseDown" :> ++i]], 
   Dynamic[EventHandler[
     Text[Style[Magnify[#, 5]], #2] & @@@ (Rest@li[[1 + Mod[i, 2]]]), 
     "MouseDown" :> {}]]}, ImageSize -> 200]]
```

Comment: Isn't the second `EventHandler[]` unnecessary?